# default dropdown value of variable

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am working on the edit screen. I need the dropdown to populate preselected values from 1 table and highlight those values from another table. 
I am able to get to the point where both values from different tables are displaying correctly in debug statement.

Problem is... 
When trying to display in the dropdown list, the preselected value is not just selecting the existing value but adding it to the dropdown.
Can you please tell me where am I enter code herewrong exactly? The problem is in   below lines:

> if (site.equals(SiteName)){
>         %>
>           <%=SiteName%>   
>        <%
>        } 
>         %>

But what is the solution for this,can anyone please tell me?

Here is my code snippet.

> for (int i = 0; siteList != null && i < siteList.size(); i++){
>                         Site s = (Site)siteList.get(i);
>                         int siteid = s.getID().intValue();
>                          site = s.getSitename();
>
> ```
>               if (site.equals(SiteName)){
>            %>
>               <option selected="selected" >  <%=SiteName%>  </option> 
>
>           <%  
>               } 
>            %> 
>               <option value="<%=siteid%>"><%=site%>  </option><%
>
>               } 
>               }catch(Exception e){
>               e.getMessage();
>               }
>           %> 
>       </select>
> ```

Comment: Seems it needs an `else` somewhere in those poorly indented codes.

Answer (score 1):

You missed out on an `else` in your code. Something like this would help:

```
<%
    for (int i = 0; siteList != null && i < siteList.size(); i++){
        Site s = (Site) siteList.get(i); 
        int siteid = s.getID().intValue(); 
        site = s.getSitename();

        if (site.equals(SiteName)){
%> 
            <option selected="selected" >  <%=SiteName%>  </option> 
<%  
        } //end of if-statement
        else{ 
%> 
            <option value="<%=siteid%>"><%=site%>  </option>
<%
        } //End of else
    } //End of for 
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
  }
%> 
</select>
```

**Note:** You've not specified where your `try`-block starts, so take care of that within your code. I could just see the `catch`-block and I'm assuming that your `try` block starts before the `for`-loop in your code.

Comment: @smiley: glad to help :) if this helped you, do consider accepting this as an answer.